# Debug/test flutter web app into chrome/safari from iPad

Tags: ios, flutter, debugging, web, ipad

I'm developing a web app with flutter. I've got no problem debugging with chrome, but when I want to test my app using chrome or safari on my iPad, I actually build my app, put it on a local server (MAMP) then open chrome on my iPad, and then browse the IP of the local server and test my app. This process takes a lot of time especially when I've got some big issue that requests many tests.
Is there a smart way to test my app with chrome from an iPad?

Thanks in advance
Peter